# How to build using Eclipse Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, rcp, tycho

We are currently building an RCP program using Ant Script.

I recently left a question about Build and found out about the keyword Tycho.

I'm trying to change the product's build method from Ant to Maven Tycho.

The document I am referencing is linked below.
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

I'm having trouble with the first part of this document and can't proceed.
As far as I know, pom.xml is automatically generated for maven projects (for example, Maven-based Spring framework projects).

But the current project is a Plug-in project, how can I create pom.xml?
Can I just create a pom.xml file?

I am having difficulties because I do not have background knowledge about each build method and structure.

Please help me.

Comment: Plug-in projects don't usually need a pom.xml because Tycho will deal with them automatically as long as they are listed in the `<modules>` section of the parent pom.xml

Comment: What greg-449 says. See the [example code of the Vogella Tycho tutorial](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example) you mentioned: Make sure to enable POM-less Tycho via [`.mvn/extensions.xml`](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example/tree/master/.mvn).